# Missing dynamic libraries on executable, but only when run as sudo

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I'm quite confused about why `libiconv.so.2` and `libcharset.so.1` are both not found but ONLY when I'm sudo-ing to a different user.  The LD_LIBRARY_PATH is exactly the same because I ran sudo with -E:

```
$ ldd `which git`
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff51975000)
    libz.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libz.so.1 (0x0000003e60600000)
    libiconv.so.2 => /internal/lib/libiconv.so.2 (0x00007f0962bdd000)
    libcrypto.so.6 => /lib64/libcrypto.so.6 (0x0000003e6a400000)
    libcharset.so.1 => /internal/lib/libcharset.so.1 (0x00007f09629db000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003e61600000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003e60a00000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x0000003e61200000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003e60200000)
$ sudo -ucgaadm -EH ldd `which git`
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff5b148000)
    libz.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libz.so.1 (0x0000003e60600000)
    libiconv.so.2 => not found
    libcrypto.so.6 => /lib64/libcrypto.so.6 (0x0000003e6a400000)
    libcharset.so.1 => not found
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003e61600000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003e60a00000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x0000003e61200000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003e60200000)
```

Just checking out the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, it seems like the path for libiconv.so.2 does exist:

```
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
...
$ sudo -ucgaadm -EH echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
... same output as previous command ...
```

The directory that should contain those libraries is also visible from my regular use as well as the sudo user:

```
$ ls /internal/lib/ -lah
total 2.5M
drwxr-xr-x 2 apsg apsggrp 4.0K Jan 31  2010 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 apsg apsggrp 4.0K Jan 31  2010 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 apsg apsggrp  212 Jan 31  2010 charset.alias
-rw-r--r-- 1 apsg apsggrp  24K Jan 31  2010 libcharset.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 apsg apsggrp  993 Jan 31  2010 libcharset.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 apsg apsggrp   19 Jan 31  2010 libcharset.so -> libcharset.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 apsg apsggrp   19 Jan 31  2010 libcharset.so.1 -> libcharset.so.1.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 apsg apsggrp  24K Jan 31  2010 libcharset.so.1.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 apsg apsggrp  969 Jan 31  2010 libiconv.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 apsg apsggrp   17 Jan 31  2010 libiconv.so -> libiconv.so.2.5.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 apsg apsggrp   17 Jan 31  2010 libiconv.so.2 -> libiconv.so.2.5.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 apsg apsggrp 1.2M Jan 31  2010 libiconv.so.2.5.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 apsg apsggrp 1.2M Jan 31  2010 preloadable_libiconv.so
$ sudo -ucgaadm -EH ls /internal/lib/ -lah
... same output as previous command ...
```

Comment: Maybe you need to configure `/etc/ld.so.conf` and then run `ldconfig`

Answer (score 0):

Try "sudo su -" then run your command
The "-" changes to root user and creates a new shell.